# How do I check if a variable is null and assign it a value if it is, in an Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not a big Access user, but I need to work with it from time to time. Now I have run into a, for me, completely new task with Access. I can solve this type of problem with SQL in MS SQL Server. But the SQL syntax in Access doesn't recognise my SQL code at all so I guess it's quite different from "regular" SQL.

Anyway, I have a table that needs to be sorted over some attributes. For this question we can take two and call them `A1` and `A2`. `A1` doesn't have any null values, `A2` does. The sort order is on `A2`:

- If `A2` has a value, sort by it.
- If `A2` is null, then sort by the value from `A1`.

I have tried so many different ways to solve this and all of them has failed. It's absolutely clear that my knowledge in Access is limited so I guess that I'm approaching this in a faulty way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NZ()`:

```
ORDER BY NZ(A2, A1)
```

NZ returns the second parameter if the first is null, otherwise it returns the first parameter.